# Design For A Class Asking Several Classes to Perform The Same Task

Tags: php, oop, laravel, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have a Laravel App and I'm creating a class that imports data.  The data is being stored in about 15 different models, so I have a Class to handle each as each has its own implementation.  Furthermore, more models may be added in the future.

I'd like to have a line of code like `$importer->import()` in an `Importer` class, which then takes all 15 of the implementation classes, and calls their `import()` methods.

However, the generic `$importer->import()` method will then look like:

```
public function __construct(ImporterOne $one, ImporterTwo $two, ImporterThree $three, etc..)
{
   $this->importerOne = $importerOne;
   $this->importerTwo = $importerTwo;
   // etc ...
   $this->importerFifteen = $importerFifteen;
}

public function import()
{
    $this->importerOne->import();
    $this->importerTwo->importer();
    // etc...
}
```

This doesn't seem very good because this class will then have 15+ dependences all essentially doing the same thing.  And then to update this, I'll need to go in here and Add / Remove dependencies and `import()` method calls.

So my solution is to delegate the the 'registration' of importers to each implementation, rather than leaving the Generic Importer class responsible.  Effectively, an Observer of sorts.  But instead of the client attaching the Observer to the Subject, each implementation attaches itself to the Subject.

```
use Importer as GenericImporter

public class importerOne {

   public function __construct(SomeModel $model, GenericImporter $importer)
   {
      $this->importer = $importer;
      $this->importer->attach($this);
   }
}

// Do the same for each implementation

// and then the generic importer

public class Importer {

   protected $importables = [];

   public function attach($import_implementation)
   {
      array_push($importables, $import_implementation); 
   }

   public function import()
   {
      foreach($this->importables as $importable)
      {
          $importable->import();
      }
   }

}
```

This seems nice and SOLID.  However, the problem is that each implementation is now using their OWN instance of the GenericImporter.  So whats the best way to go about this?  Do I implement the Generic Importer as a Singleton?  Also, for my research purposes, does this fall into a certain design pattern?  It seems similar to an ObservorPattern except that each Observer is registering itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that:

> the problem is that each implementation is now using their OWN
>   instance of the GenericImporter

I don't think it would be a problem because `GenericImporter` is only a dependency you are injecting in the implementations. Furthermore, the `GenericImporter` you're passing around **is always the same object**, as it will be passed by 'reference'

**EDIT**

Regarding the comment below, when you say:

> when a dependency is resolved through the IoC Container, it isn't
>   passing by reference. It's instantiating a new instance of that Class

It depends on how you do the binding in the ioC Container: if you use `instance()`, to bind the Importer in this way:

```
$importer = new Importer();
$this->app->instance( Importer::class, $importer );
```

then the same `$importer` instance will be resolved out of the ioC container when an `Importer` dependency is requested in your app.

**END EDIT**

Anyway, i would improve the design by adding an interface; something like this:

```
//INTERFACE FOR IMPORTABLES
interface Importable
{
    public function __construct( Model $model ); 
    public function import();
}

//IMPLEMENTATION OF IMPORTABLES
class importerOne implements Importable 
{   
   public function __construct( SomeModel $model )
   {
   }

   public function import()
   {
       //logic
   }
}

//THE IMPORTER CLASS
public class Importer 
{    
   protected $importables = [];

   //attach any Importable
   public function attach( Importable $import_implementation )
   {
      array_push( $this->importables, $import_implementation) ; 
   }

   //trigger Importable::import
   public function import()
   {
      foreach($this->importables as $importable)
      {
          $importable->import();
      }
   }   
}
```

If for some specific reason you don't want to pass the dependency of `Importer` to your importables, why don't you attach the importables from the client? Something like this:

```
$importer = new Importer();

$importer->attach( $importable_1 );
$importer->attach( $importable_2 );
//$importer->attach( $importable_n );

$importer->import();
```

This way the importers don't need that you pass them the `Importer` dependency

Depending on how you have your importables built, you could also consider building and storing all of them in an array and pass the array to the Importer:

```
$importer->attachAll( $importables_array );
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  However, in Laravel, when a dependency is resolved through the IoC Container, it isn't passing by reference.  It's instantiating a new instance of that Class (in this case, Importer).  Setting it up in the Client code make sense, but basically, I'm trying to avoid a situation where if/when the requirements change and there are more implementations, I'm not constantly modifying methods/classes/client code to append/remove implementations

Comment: @dtj : for the first thing check my edit above. For the second: if you have more than one point in your client where you have to attach the imporables to the importer, you'd better use the observer way

Comment: thanks for that tip about the instance, I didn't know that.  I suppose the last aspect of this: Basically, all these Implementations are depending the Generic Importer class to execute their functionality.  As of now, I still have to instantiate each implementation somewhere in my code, to trigger the dependency injection of the Generic Importer into each implementation.  I was hoping to basically define all the implementations somewhere (maybe in a Service Provder) and when I called $importer->import() from somewhere, the app knows to gather those implementations and instantiate them

Comment: @dtj : Yes, probably this is the best way: first build the `Importer`, then build in one place all the importables, then trigger import. It seems a good solution to me. Probably if you initially build an array with all the importables list (i.e: `importerOne::class`, ecc ) you could find a way to loop the array and instantiate all the importables automatically

Answer (score 0):

Few things... 1) Mind you... it has been years since I touched PHP... but design patterns are part of my PhD focus... But... I do recommend you try to stick as close as possible to the naming conventions of patterns (or at least document the classes/methods as the roles they play in a pattern. Because I get the feeling you would have an easier time implementing this if you did that.

You actually seem to be implementing an -inverse- [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Traditionally the Subject object keeps an array of observers that 'are' observing it (You'll just have 1 observer, but the pattern supports many). Then calls "notifyObservers()" which loops through all Observer and calls 'notify()' for each one. You seem to be trying to send the notification the 'other way'. This is likely why you are getting multiple instances of 'GenericImporter'. You want 'importerOne' to 'notify' the 'importer' but the Observer pattern would have you do it the other way around, you would want the 'importerOne', etc. to be the 'Subject'(s) and the 'Importer' to be the (single) 'Observer'.

This design might be a little bit less natural in the way you want your program to work, but that's how the pattern is designed. You have the "Observer" doing too much. The 'Observer' is a passive actor and just gets their 'update(Observable o, Object arg)' method called when the Observed (Subject) class calls "notifyObservers()". If you design it this way, your "observer" class can be VERY simple... (like the Java example below) As long as you create a base class that implements the 'Observable' functionality that all your Subjects classes extend (importerOne, importerTwo, etc).

The [Observer] implements a 'notify()' method/function. This 'notify()' is what is called when the Observer is 'notified', not that it wants to 'notify' the other end. Here is the wiki Java example with detailed comments (I'll explain this since I haven't touch PHP in years, and can do a better job explaining the java example on the wiki page)

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Scanner;

// This is the [Subject](Observed) class
class EventSource extends Observable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String response = new Scanner(System.in).next();
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(response);
        }
    }
    // Notice that EventSource 'extends' [Observable], which means it has...
    // the following methods available to it also...(among others)...
    //
    // addObserver(Observer o) // adds a new Observer
    // deleteObserver(Observer o) // deletes a specific Observer
    // notifyObservers(Object arg) // Notifies all observers with some 'arg'
    //
    // Notice that 'notifyObservers(    )' is the only one called
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Observable;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    out.println("Enter Text >");

    // This is the [Subject](Observed class/object)
    EventSource eventSource = new EventSource();

    // here the 'Subject' is registering the observer
    eventSource.addObserver(
        // This is java 8 notation for a new anonymous class
        // This creates an instance of the [Observer](link below) Interface
        // The Observer Object only has one method...
        // update(Observable o, Object arg){}
        // The below code is the 'implementation' of the...
        // 'update(Observable o, Object arg)' method
        // 'obj' is the object that was being observed, 
        // 'arg' is the object passed into 'notifyObservers(Object)'...
        // from within the [Subject](observed) object.
        (Observable obj, Object arg) -> 
        {  
             // This code here is what is called when an Observed object 
             // calls 'notifyObservers()' (in this case only '1' observer)
             out.println("\nReceived response: " + arg);
        } 
    );
}
```

[Observer JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

Hopefully this will help you adjust your program to use the observer pattern in a more traditional way, and will allow you to note in your documentation what you are doing/etc.

Comment: thanks for the insight, but my Subject is the `GenericImporter` (it is One) and holds an Array of and my Observors which are ImportOne, ImportTwo, ImportThree (the Many).  And my Subject calls `import()` -- i.e. notify() -- on each.  However, my Observers are attaching themselves to the  Subject, rather than being attached in the client code.  As such, each one is has it's own Instance of `GenericImporter`

Comment: @dtj You'll want to clean up the design logic somewhat too, make 'importerOne' etc. all extend some parent class "ImporterBase" that implements the Observer notify() method. That way you have better design overall. This will allow you to more easily label your classes and note the Observer Pattern.

Comment: Thanks   But really what I'm asking: is this the most appropriate solution for my problem?

Comment: I'd say so, after you tidy it up. The 'trick' to using patterns well is really  naming and then documentation. If you were to use 'visit' and 'accept' Someone would likely think it is the "visitor pattern" at first, but if you use "notify(Object)" and "notifyObservers(Object)" then it is more easily identifiable as the 'observer pattern', even without proper documentation stating so. But WITH doc, you're golden. Plus sticking to those names/conventions will help you with logical issues, like how you had each Subject creating new Observers when you only wanted 1, etc.